# fscanf returning suspicious data in C

Tags: c

Here is the website of the data files: [Group Data Release](https://gax.sjtu.edu.cn/data/Group.html)
And here I am using the catalogs of SDSS_MTV (the third section from the bottom of the webpage).

The data are split into 8 parts. I am trying to read one of these files (such as "Fillingfactor_sdssMth12_80Mpc").
Actually, I am using `fscanf()` to get the data of "Fillingfactor_sdssMth12_80Mpc". Some of them show the values far greater than 1, that's unreasonable because the filing factor cannot exceed 1.

Here is the excerpt of this file (the first 5 rows):

```
609d 6c34 417e edb0 2664 0231 4452 3931
d948 2bb2 d877 15b2 0f5b e4b1 b646 9631
470e e3b1 06e2 3fb2 3483 f4b1 2c3d 11b2
6d86 89b1 8135 04b2 005c 44b2 d9eb a4b0
ad80 04b2 8dfb fcb1 03b0 3d32 afc6 4432
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
        int i;
        int Nx,Ny,Nz,itemp;
        FILE *fp;
        char filename[256];
        sprintf(filename,"Fillingfactor_sdssMth12_80Mpc");
        Nx=494;
        Ny=892;
        Nz=499;
        float *quan = (float *)malloc(Nx*Ny*Nz*sizeof(float));
        fp = fopen(filename,"r");
        fread(&itemp,1,sizeof(float),fp);
        // Checks the length of the table.
        printf("itemp = %i\n", itemp);
        if(itemp/sizeof(float) != Nx*Ny*Nz)
        {
            printf("error! itemp=%d\n",itemp);
            exit(1);
        }
        for(i=0;i<Nx*Ny*Nz;i++)
        {
            fscanf(fp,"%f",&quan[i]);
            printf("grid %i is: %.4lf\n", i, quan[i]);        
        }
        fclose(fp);
}
```

Could someone explain me what is wrong?

Comment: Where is `fscanf`?

Comment: Please add an excerpt of the file. And not expect other to download some >800MB file...

Comment: But also without the file: for initialisation use calloc (or malloc+memset) and check the return value of fscanf. Probably you have an unexpected input in that file.

Comment: The `fscanf()` function is trying to read a text representation of a floating-point number, but you're working with a binary file. Use `fread()` as per the sample code in the Readme page.

Comment: `fread(&itemp,1,sizeof(float)` `itemp` is an `int`, not a `float`.

Comment: @KamilCuk: I see, this row only checks the length of the table.

Comment: @lnksz: Yep, here I show the first five rows of the "Fillingfactor_sdssMth12_80Mpc".

Comment: Please note that both [`fread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) and [`fscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) actually *return* a value that should be checked.

Comment: do you know the encoding of this file? floating point numbers can be represented in many ways... Also endianness must be considered. But if the file is binary encoded, then you cannot work with fscanf as if it would be text